# How to move to the top of the element?

Tags: javascript

I know that `.scrollTo(0,0)` works for the `window` and returns you to the top of the page. But my goal is to return to the top of the certain element on the page. How can I do that?

```js
function returnToTopElement(clickingObjId, element){
 let clickOn = document.getElementById(clickingObjId);
 let topElement = document.getElementById(element);
 clickOn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  topElement.scrollTo(0,0);
 });
};

returnToTopElement("top-button", "elem-b");
```

```css
    .menu{
   position: fixed;
   background-color: red;
   width: 100%;
   height: 30px;
   top: 0;
    }
    .elem-a{
      height: 200px;
      width: 200px;
      background-color: #f6f6f6;
      color: black;
    }
    .elem-b{
      height: 300px;
      width: 200px;
      background-color: #263B42;
      color: white;
    }
    .top-button{
      margin-top: 200px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .top-button:hover{
      background-color: #b2b2b2;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="menu"> Menu </div>
    <div>  
      <div class="elem-a"> a </div>
      <div class="elem-b" id="elem-b"> 

      b

      <p class="top-button" id="top-button"> Return to the top </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Just use a link instead of a <p>? when clicked, it will jump to the element matching your ID, like an anchor. If you need more info, I will put it into a full answer.

Comment: @Jeroen Bourgois Oh, I didn't know that you can do that, thanks!

Comment: But, another problem occurred, my fixed element covers a part of the element that moved to the top. Is there a way to move this element to x amount of pixels away from the top? (I'm going to update code here rn)

Comment: No not really. In the past I used to make sure there was some (or a lot) of `padding-top` on the anchored elements, then that works. If not, you will probably need something like in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HTMLElement.offsetTop` is the distance between this element's top border to its offsetParent's top border, not to the top of the document.
It's also oddly complicated to calculate the relative distance between two elements. In your case, you can calculate it using the following:

```
topElement.getBoundingClientRect().top - document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect().top
```

But this doesn't account for the top margin if there's any. So you might have to go further **IF** you want to include the top margin like this.

```
topElement.getBoundingClientRect().top 
- topElement.getComputedStyle().getPropertyValue('margin-top')
- document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect().top
```

You might be wondering if there's a less cumbersome way, but really, this is what you have to do in most cases.